# Calling a php function in ajax url

Tags: php, jquery

Hello I'm trying to call a php function in ajax url. This is how i do it.

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "<?php echo URL; ?>controller/contact/send",
     data: $("#pm").serialize(),
     success: function(data) {
         if(data == "true") {
            $("#pm").fadeOut("fast", function(){
               $(this).before("Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)");
                setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
            });
         }
     }
 });
```

in the line `url: "<?php echo URL; ?>controller/contact/send",`

contact is the php file and send is the function.

**contact.php**

```
class Contact extends Controller {

     public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();

    }

    function index() {
        $this->view->render('index/index');
    }

    function send() {
         $mail = new Mail();
         $mail->sendTo("testmail@gmail.com");
         $mail->userMail($_POST['email']);
         $mail->content(nl2br($_POST['msg']));
         $mail->subject("New feedback");
         if($mail->send()){
            echo "true";
         } else {
            echo "false";
         }
      }
   }
```

I tested the send() function without using ajax call and I can receive emails. But when I use ajax call I'm not getting any emails.

Comment: try with this url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/contact/send",

Comment: 1) Using the console, check whether the appropriate data is being POSTed to the URL. 2) Check whether it is being POSTed to the RIGHT URL.

Comment: See the page source in browser and check whether the url specified is correct or not.

Comment: @shuvo `<?php echo base_url('contact/send'); ?>` would be better (does urlencoding).

Comment: Yes thank you got it working using <?php echo URL; ?>contact/send or <?php echo base_url('contact/send'); ?>

Comment: you can check on firebug console when ever button click check console where your request is goin copy that url and run in browser check it weather its working or not

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "<?php echo URL; ?>contact/send" ,
```

or

```
url: "<?php echo base_url('contact/send'); ?>",
```